# WPF application exe causes problems on C:

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, exe

I have a very strange problem. I have written a program in WPF & C# with a postgres database. I start the exe on my pc the program works fine. Then I copy the debug folder to a USB. Install all necessary Netframework, the database etc. on another computer. Then I start the program there, it starts and I can use it but it crashes when I call a specific UserControl. Now comes the strange thing, if I start the exe from the USB stick, the program works fine without crashing. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Apparently, you aren't logging error messages (ie: exceptions). I would start with modifying your code so that it logs error messages. Next, create an installer for your program and use that to install your program onto another computer.

Comment: a dependency might be missing on the 2nd computer

Comment: At first i use an installer for my programm, but then works even less than this one usercontrol. Great idea with a logger, i check it out. Thnaks

Comment: Try checking the Event Viewer; crash details might be logged under “Application”

Comment: i have try and catch functions built in everywhere, but none of them are triggered

Comment: @ReillyWood, how i checked the event viewer, if i have no compiler

Comment: The Event Viewer is an application that comes preinstalled with Windows. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer

Comment: It is so stupid. I found out that it was a path problem. He will open a .png, but it is not the right path.

Comment: consider registering `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` to not litter the code with catches

Answer (score 0):

**Easy**

Build > Publish x

Select your location

then click

[image]

[image]

Make sure it is self-contained and win-x64

This makes sure all of the things are contained directly in the exe without relying on .NET